# Java Heap Size Error In Bamboo

Tags: java, maven, bamboo

While building a project in bamboo using maven I am getting out of memory exception. However project is built properly in local environment. Tried to increasing heap size in maven-opts but there is no luck. Below is the stack trace:

```
com.atlassian.bamboo.repository.RepositoryException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.trigger.DefaultChangeDetectionManager.collectChangesSinceLastBuildInternal(DefaultChangeDetectionManager.java:371)
 at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.trigger.DefaultChangeDetectionManager.collectChangesSinceRevisions(DefaultChangeDetectionManager.java:259)
 at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.trigger.DefaultChangeDetectionManager.collectChangesSinceRevisions(DefaultChangeDetectionManager.java:161)
 at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.trigger.DefaultChangeDetectionManager.collectAllChangesSinceLastBuild(DefaultChangeDetectionManager.java:127)
 at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.trigger.ManualBuildDetectionAction.performDelayedChangeDetection(ManualBuildDetectionAction.java:173)
 at com.atlassian.bamboo.chains.ChainExecutionManagerImpl$2.getChainState(ChainExecutionManagerImpl.java:209)
 at com.atlassian.bamboo.chains.ChainExecutionManagerImpl.tryStartChainState(ChainExecutionManagerImpl.java:262)
 at com.atlassian.bamboo.chains.ChainExecutionManagerImpl.delayedStart(ChainExecutionManagerImpl.java:198)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16764.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:304)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
 at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
 at $Proxy98.delayedStart(Unknown Source)
 at com.atlassian.bamboo.plan.PlanExecutionManagerImpl$1$1$1.call(PlanExecutionManagerImpl.java:383)
 at com.atlassian.bamboo.plan.PlanExecutionManagerImpl$1$1$1.call(PlanExecutionManagerImpl.java:378)
 at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.ManagedLocks$ManagedLockImpl.withLock(ManagedLocks.java:312)
 at com.atlassian.bamboo.plan.PlanExecutionLockServiceImpl.lock(PlanExecutionLockServiceImpl.java:81)
 at com.atlassian.bamboo.plan.PlanExecutionManagerImpl.doWithProcessLock(PlanExecutionManagerImpl.java:725)
 at com.atlassian.bamboo.plan.PlanExecutionManagerImpl.access$200(PlanExecutionManagerImpl.java:123)
 at com.atlassian.bamboo.plan.PlanExecutionManagerImpl$1$1.run(PlanExecutionManagerImpl.java:377)
 at com.atlassian.bamboo.build.pipeline.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory$2.run(NamedThreadFactory.java:55)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: Have you checked https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMKB/OutOfMemory+Errors+in+Bamboo#OutOfMemoryErrorsinBamboo-Heapmemory

Comment: yes modified maven_opts too but there is no luck.

Answer (score 2):

In the full log of your build, you should be able to read something like this:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms128m -Xmx2048m
```

In the Bamboo Maven task, there is a text box `Environment variables` with as a desciption:

> Extra environment variables. e.g. `MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx256m -Xms128m"`. You can add multiple parameters separated by a space.

There, you can set in the case of `_JAVA_OPTIONS`:

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms256m -Xmx4096m"
```